# sudo in bash script: Doesn't always wait for password

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, sudo

I have a simple bash script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo ./some_other_script_01
sudo ./some_other_script_02
```

When I execute this script, I **always** see the password prompt, as usual:

```
[sudo] password for user:
```

However sometimes, inexplicably, before I have typed my password, `./some_other_script_01` starts getting executed (presumably without root permissions). This happens even though it *did* prompt me for a password (which I didn't yet provide).

Currently, when this happens, I have to kill the scripts and start again (so that they get executed with root privileges).

Comment: Is `sudo` configured with `passwd_timeout` set to some too small value in the `sudoers` file?

Comment: If you want to *force* sudo to ask for a password, use the `-k` option. Check your man page for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sudo once is enough, just start the `wrapper.sh` with sudo. Check if you have root permission in the script no more sudo calls needed.

```
sudo ./wrapper.sh
```

wrapper.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
  then echo "Please run as root"
  exit
fi

./some_other_script_01
./some_other_script_02
```

Comment: Thank you. I've marked this as the answer because it's the right thing to do, but it still doesn't solve my mystery. I will keep investigating.